# rm: cannot remove `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission deniedLED]

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, user-permissions

I am unable to start the Apache server on linux

I have tried :

```
service httpd start
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

but both commands are showing :--

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission deniedLED]
rm: cannot remove `/var/lock/subsys/httpd': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission denied
```

Please tell me, If any issue

Comment: Run the same command with `sudo`

Answer (score 7):

Run the command again as root and try restart.